# Angular2 Unit test for Observable.interval

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have a service that polls data from server every 500 milliseconds. For this i have used `Observable.interval()`.

Below is my code. I want to write the unit test for this service

service.ts:

```
pollData() {
       Observable.interval(500).mergeMap(() =>
       this._http
      .get(url, { headers: headers })
      .map((resp: Response) => resp.json())
});
```

Service.spec.ts:

```
it('should get the response correctly', async(inject(
  [SomeService, MockBackend], (service, mockBackend) => {
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: 
      mockResponse})));
   });
    const result = service.pollData();

    result.subscribe(response => {
       expect(response).toEqual(mockResponse);
    });
  }
)));
```

Getting the error on running ng test:

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout
>   specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`fakeAsync`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) testing function and the [`tick`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick) function to simulate the interval. Here is an example method and associated test demonstrating this behavior.

#### Component Method

```js
public testMe() {
  return Observable.interval(500).mergeMap((period: number) => {
    return Observable.of(period);
  });
}
```

#### Test Method

```js
it('should test method with interval', fakeAsync(() => {
  const obs = component.testMe();
  let currentVal = undefined;
  const sub = obs.subscribe((v) => {
    currentVal = v;
  });
  tick(500);
  expect(currentVal).toEqual(0);
  tick(500);
  expect(currentVal).toEqual(1);
  tick(500);
  expect(currentVal).toEqual(2);
  /* ... */
  sub.unsubscribe(); // must unsubscribe or Observable will keep emitting resulting in an error
}));
```

Comment: I assume this approach can't be used if the method does not return the Observable? For example, I have an interval running inside my ngOnInit so I have no access to the Observable in the test.

Comment: If you don't have access to the observable then it will be difficult to test. Perhaps it is created from a service that you can stub or there is another value that is the result of the inner observable that can be tested?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the default timeout interval for `jasmine`. Assuming your test requires 30 seconds, you could do the following :

```
it('should get the response correctly', async(inject(
  [SomeService, MockBackend], (service, mockBackend) => {
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: 
      mockResponse})));
   });
    const result = service.pollData();

    result.subscribe(response => {
       expect(response).toEqual(mockResponse);
    });
  }
   // increasing the jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL to 30s.
)), 30000);
```